# Can i implement v-model to a div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

im encountering a problem is i need to reload the page to see the Sub-category

[image]

When i click the arrow icon the Sub-category menu will appear like this

[image]

So i have tried like using the tag.openModal to display the subcategory when clicked

```
<div
   v-for="(tag, i) in listItem.categories"
   :key="i"
   v-on:click="handleClickCategory(tag,i)"
>
        <nuxt-link
          :to="`/category/parentCate`"
          :key="i"
        >
          <span class="tagDetail" @click="$emit('closeSideBar')">
            {{ tag.name }} 
          </span>
        </nuxt-link>
        <span @click="onClickTag(tag, tag.subCates, tag.id)" v-if="tag.subCates.length"
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
        </span>
        <div v-if="tag.openModal">
          <div v-for="(subCate) in tag.subCates" :key="subCate.id">
            <nuxt-link :to="`/category/childCate`"  class="subCateItem" >
              {{subCate.name}}
            </nuxt-link>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

But only i tab-out will the component apprear.
So i have think of something like the v-model but clearly v-model doesnt support something like a div but rather than an input, dialog, or v-select.

How can i achieve what i want guys.
Thanks for reading

**EDIT:**

so when i say tab-out is that my list of category will be show if i click a button, my list of category will be appear like this

[image]

As you can see from my code is that if i click a category, i will emit an event to close this popup ( my list of category ). So after i have click it the popup will be close and when i click the button which call the popup this will happen
[image]

But still the thing is i want my subcategory to be shown when i click the arrow icon, not like this

Comment: I didn't get your line..where you say tab out

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly

Comment: yes I dont quite understand the question either. `v-model` is for binding data, then you have `v-if` and `v-show` to conditionally show elements.